# JavaScript - Load many tiny files

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, download

My JavaScript application has to load many micro text files from my web server asynchronously (there're about 200 * 5kB files). I know that downloading 1 large file is far more fast than downloading many tiny files. But I cannot predict which files are gonna be loaded (the client makes requests) and I have tons of files like this.

**How can I speed up the transfer of those files?**

I thought about concatenating requested files with PHP. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

"I thought about concatenating requested files with PHP. Is that a good idea?"

We do the same thing in production with a servlet in java and it works quite well. But, to get it right we had to cache the concatenated files, don't read them for each request. The file IO  has a lot of overhead.

Here's a list of [PHP cache tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators). Given a highly cursory look at the doc for xcache you should be able to write a php file that collects all of your individual files and concatenates them and then store that in memory to be used as a resource.

Comment: At least 100 files, and we slurp them up from multiple sub projects.

Comment: Ok! And how can I cache files using PHP?

Comment: I added a paragraph to try and point you in the right direction. FYI I'm not a php guy.